# Como alinear los botones de exportacion en la linea que el search en datatable

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, datatables

Buenas tardes un saludo tengo un problema con alinear unos botones en la misma linea del search. estoy utilizando la plantilla AdminLTE3. Lo curioso es que en la plantilla del sitio web aparecen alineados pero cuando la descargo los botones no aparecen y los implemento por medio del dom y me salen un div sobre el search [Enlace AdminLTE3](https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/pages/tables/data.html)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo js con la que inicializo mi tabla

```
$('#tablacarreras').DataTable({
//!DIRECCION DEL ARCHIVO QUE CONTIENE LOS DATOS A MOSTRAR POR AJAX
"ajax": "ajax/datatable-carreras.php",
"responsive": true,
"aServerSide": true,
"autoWidth": false,
"deferRender": true,
"retrieve": true,
"processing": true,
"paging": true,
 "dom": 'Bfrtip',
"buttons": ["copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print"],
"language": {
    "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
    "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
    "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
    "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
    "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_",
    "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0",
    "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
    "sInfoPostFix": "",
    "sSearch": "Buscar:",
    "sUrl": "",
    "sInfoThousands": ",",
    "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst": "Primero",
        "sLast": "Último",
        "sNext": "Siguiente",
        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
    },
    "oAria": {
        "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
        "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
    }
}});
```

Comment: 2 cosas, edita el codigo para que la ultima llave quede junto al codigo, y por favor comparte tu HTML del datatable para replicar el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola @Jerson Josue Rodriguez, replicando tu datatable lo que me fije en la template es que al wrapper le hace un align right asi que he logrado solucionarlo haciendo dos cositas:

1. Le agregas una clase a tu elemento Label (Search), yo la llame lineLabel y le estableces un `display: inline-flex;`
2. En tu hoja de estilos agregas la siguiente instruccion que tu template la tiene, pero de alguna forma no se te muestra:

   ```
    div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_filter {
       text-align: right;
    }
   ```

Deberas crear una media Query para organizar el responsive como deseas que se vea.

```css
.lineLabel{
display: inline-flex;
}

div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_filter{
text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card-body">
    <div id="example1_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper dt-bootstrap4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="dt-buttons btn-group flex-wrap"> <button
                        class="btn btn-secondary buttons-copy buttons-html5" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1"
                        type="button"><span>Copy</span></button> <button
                        class="btn btn-secondary buttons-csv buttons-html5" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1"
                        type="button"><span>CSV</span></button> <button
                        class="btn btn-secondary buttons-excel buttons-html5" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1"
                        type="button"><span>Excel</span></button> <button
                        class="btn btn-secondary buttons-pdf buttons-html5" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1"
                        type="button"><span>PDF</span></button> <button class="btn btn-secondary buttons-print"
                        tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" type="button"><span>Print</span></button>
                    <div class="btn-group"><button
                            class="btn btn-secondary buttons-collection dropdown-toggle buttons-colvis" tabindex="0"
                            aria-controls="example1" type="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                            aria-expanded="false"><span>Column visibility</span></button></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <div id="example1_filter" class="dataTables_filter"><label class="lineLabel">Search:<input type="search"
                            class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="example1"></label></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable dtr-inline" role="grid"
                    aria-describedby="example1_info">
                    <thead>
                        <tr role="row">
                            <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                                aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Rendering engine: activate to sort column descending">
                                Rendering engine</th>
                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                                aria-label="Browser: activate to sort column ascending">Browser</th>
                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                                aria-label="Platform(s): activate to sort column ascending">Platform(s)</th>
                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                                aria-label="Engine version: activate to sort column ascending">Engine version</th>
                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                                aria-label="CSS grade: activate to sort column ascending">CSS grade</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr role="row" class="odd">
                            <td class="dtr-control sorting_1" tabindex="0">Gecko</td>
                            <td>Firefox 1.0</td>
                            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                            <td>1.7</td>
                            <td>A</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr role="row" class="even">
                            <td class="dtr-control sorting_1" tabindex="0">Gecko</td>
                            <td>Firefox 1.5</td>
                            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                            <td>1.8</td>
                            <td>A</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr role="row" class="odd">
                            <td class="dtr-control sorting_1" tabindex="0">Gecko</td>
                            <td>Firefox 2.0</td>
                            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                            <td>1.8</td>
                            <td>A</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr role="row" class="even">
                            <td class="dtr-control sorting_1" tabindex="0">Gecko</td>
                            <td>Firefox 3.0</td>
                            <td>Win 2k+ / OSX.3+</td>
                            <td>1.9</td>
                            <td>A</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr role="row" class="odd">
                            <td class="sorting_1 dtr-control">Gecko</td>
                            <td>Camino 1.0</td>
                            <td>OSX.2+</td>
                            <td>1.8</td>
                            <td>A</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr role="row" class="even">
                            <td class="sorting_1 dtr-control">Gecko</td>
                            <td>Camino 1.5</td>
                            <td>OSX.3+</td>
                            <td>1.8</td>
                            <td>A</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr role="row" class="odd">
                            <td class="sorting_1 dtr-control">Gecko</td>
                            <td>Netscape 7.2</td>
                            <td>Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2</td>
                            <td>1.7</td>
                            <td>A</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr role="row" class="even">
                            <td class="sorting_1 dtr-control">Gecko</td>
                            <td>Netscape Browser 8</td>
                            <td>Win 98SE+</td>
                            <td>1.7</td>
                            <td>A</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr role="row" class="odd">
                            <td class="sorting_1 dtr-control">Gecko</td>
                            <td>Netscape Navigator 9</td>
                            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                            <td>1.8</td>
                            <td>A</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr role="row" class="even">
                            <td class="sorting_1 dtr-control">Gecko</td>
                            <td>Mozilla 1.0</td>
                            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>A</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Rendering engine</th>
                            <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Browser</th>
                            <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Platform(s)</th>
                            <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Engine version</th>
                            <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">CSS grade</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5">
                <div class="dataTables_info" id="example1_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing 1 to 10 of 57
                    entries</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
                <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="example1_paginate">
                    <ul class="pagination">
                        <li class="paginate_button page-item previous disabled" id="example1_previous"><a href="#"
                                aria-controls="example1" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0" class="page-link">Previous</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="paginate_button page-item active"><a href="#" aria-controls="example1"
                                data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0" class="page-link">1</a></li>
                        <li class="paginate_button page-item "><a href="#" aria-controls="example1" data-dt-idx="2"
                                tabindex="0" class="page-link">2</a></li>
                        <li class="paginate_button page-item "><a href="#" aria-controls="example1" data-dt-idx="3"
                                tabindex="0" class="page-link">3</a></li>
                        <li class="paginate_button page-item "><a href="#" aria-controls="example1" data-dt-idx="4"
                                tabindex="0" class="page-link">4</a></li>
                        <li class="paginate_button page-item "><a href="#" aria-controls="example1" data-dt-idx="5"
                                tabindex="0" class="page-link">5</a></li>
                        <li class="paginate_button page-item "><a href="#" aria-controls="example1" data-dt-idx="6"
                                tabindex="0" class="page-link">6</a></li>
                        <li class="paginate_button page-item next" id="example1_next"><a href="#"
                                aria-controls="example1" data-dt-idx="7" tabindex="0" class="page-link">Next</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias, logre resolver de la siguiente manera manipulando el DOM segun la documetacion el resultado fue el siguiente tal como lo queria. Saludos

```
dom: '<"row"<"col-sm-12 col-md-4"l><"col-sm-12 col-md-4"<"dt-buttons btn-group flex-wrap"B>><"col-sm-12 col-md-4"f>>t<"row"<"col-sm-12 col-md-6"i><"col-sm-12 col-md-6"p>>',
buttons: [{
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo resolví colocando lo siguiente

```
dom: '<"top"Bf>rt<"bottom"lpi><"clear">',
  buttons: [{
    extend: 'print',
    text: '<i class="fa fa-print"></i> Imprimir',
    filename: 'Print_list',
  }],
```

y así quedaron alineados el botón, en mi caso, imprimir y el de búsqueda por filtro

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo resolví de esta manera para ordenar el dom de manera peronalizada:
(lfBtip)

```js
dom: '<"row"' +
            '<"col-sm-12 col-md-6"l><"col-sm-12 col-md-6"f>>' +
            '<"row"' +
            '<"col-sm-12 col-md-6:eq(0)"><"dt-buttons btn-group flex-wrap"B>>' +
            't' +
            '<"row"' +
            '<"col-sm-12 col-md-6"i><"col-sm-12 col-md-6"p>>',
```

Pueden utilizarlo para todos los botones que brinda data table, ahí les incluyo configuración personalizada de algunos botones.

```js
buttons: [
            {
                //COPY
                extend: 'copy',
                text: '<i class="fas fa-copy"></i> Copiar',
                title: 'Lista de categorias',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [0, 1]
                },
                className: 'btn btn-light btn-sm'
            },
            {
                //EXCEL
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                text: '<i class="text-success fas fa-file-excel"></i><a class="text-success"> Excel</a>',
                title: 'Lista de categorias',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [0, 1]
                },
                className: 'btn btn-light btn-sm'
            },
         ]
```